# how to edit a css selector in order to shorten the amount of characters used in file

Tags: css

I want to edit a css property(background) so that I can make it shorter.
I have it throughout my file and my file is too long.
e.g instead of having to write "ul {background:white;}" i could write "ul {b:white;}" or something similar.
Is this possible?

Comment: Now why would you want to do that?

Comment: @NabeelSheikh In order to reduce traffic -> load time (I guess)

Comment: how many "background"s could you have in 1 css?  maybe it should be on a parent element an overridden as needed?

Comment: @AwokeKnowing He just made an example. As far as I understand he just want's to minimize his file size which gets transmitted to the user.

Comment: Its not actually for any practical reason! Its for a class competition.

Comment: I have to get the css file as small as possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. However, you can use a tool like [CSS Minifier](http://cssminifier.com/) to shrink the size of your CSS in general. Depending on what language you're using on the backend, there are tools to do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually already used a minifier. My code is: i,th,a[href^="http:"]{background:#F0F}
li,main h1 {background:olive}
ul,li li,tr:nth-child(even){background:aqua}
li li a,#blog h1{background:#FFF}
#blog{background:lime}
.likes{background:#FF0}

Comment: I can't think of any other way to make it shorter!

Comment: If you can't make it any shorter, then it's as short as it can be! Save, of course, for what Cristy's answer mentions, which is enabling compression on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

Take in consideration that you may already be doing something similar without knowing :). It's called [gzip compression](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/).

Long story short, most servers have already activated the option to compress all data sent to a browser. The compression is done in a similar way to what you want, long words that appear more often are replaced with shorter words.

Answer (score 0):

maybe in javascript you could add it to all the elements. the correct answer may depend on what is "restricting" you. why do you say it's too long?

Answer (score 0):

if you're really that paranoid with page load speed... maybe you could do something like this:

- make all your css using less or sass... or something similar, the idea is to use a mixin that replaces all long names with compressed ones (like a "uglifier" for css). i.e:

  - "background-color"  becomes "bc"
  - "font-size" becomes "fs"
- compress it with gzip, cache headers, etc.
- then use a client JS compiler (like less.js or sass.js) that compiles your css code into normal css on client side

however... this may not be practical, because all the bytes you save on css will be replaced by the JS compiler you'll have to load

maybe in the future when all browsers will have a less or sass compiler integrated n_n

Hope this helps

Comment: Interesting but not something I can implement. Any solution has to be from within my css file.